# Writing program output to web page and keeping server and program in different files

Tags: html, http, go

I'm writing web frontend for my go program that represents user input as ascii art characters. [Something like this](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20).

It makes sense for me to keep server and program that converts user input to ascii art representation in different `.go` files. I want to call my program from `server.go`, after I've taken FormValues from user. How can I accomplish this? I've already spent considerable time doing my research and cannot really find anything about it. I'm certain that this is possible.

Also how should I go about displaying my program output at webpage I've created? At the moment my program will store output inside []string and uses for loop to print out lines. It's easy for me to change output data type if that is required. Just looking for some insight to accomplish this in a smart way and not use something like fmt.Fprint() to display result.

Hope that my questions are clear and understandable. I've only been learning programming for weeks and feel like I'm missing an link from a chain at the moment.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. Posts are free, so you can ask more than one if you want to, of course.

Comment: And for each question: what have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter? Be specific.